# PHP. Возможно ли замена значения переменной сессии при жестком выключении компьютера клиента?

Tags: php, сессия

На практике заказчик столкнулся с ситуацией.
Заказчик - клиент, авторизовался на сайте. В результате в сессию помещается некий зашифрованный идентификатор клиента. После этого батарея на ноутбуке заканчивается и он вырубается. После включения, клиент выполняет стандартные для него действия:

1. Закрывает окно "Разрушительный сбой".
2. Время сбивается на 2015 год, и устанавливается время правильное.
3. запускает браузер Mozilla Firefox, вводит пароль от хранилища паролей.
4. в закрепленных вкладках висит ЛК, где собственно и происходила авторизация описанная выше.

В результате сегодня когда он открыл браузер после перезапуска, а в ЛК он был авторизован под другим аккаунтом. Под аккаунтом, который был в браузере он может и авторизовался раньше, но не в последнее время.

Отсюда вопрос, как такое вообще возможно?.

Единственное предположение, что после этого, так называемого, разрушительного сбоя, восстановились данные браузера куки и т.п. из резервного хранилища или еще откуда нибудь. Сам он ничего лично не делал.

Попробовал выполнить еще раз такую же процедуру, но после загрузки в браузере висел аккаунт того клиента, по которым он был авторизован до отключения питания. Т.е. все нормально.

Буду признателен любому мнению, спасибо.

Comment: Если он сначала выполнил п.3, то браузер не нашел валидной по дате куки не смог привязаться к сессии и была сгенерирована новая сессия и кука, потом клиент, увидев неправильное время, выполнил п.2, а потом п.3. И браузер снова не нашел валидной куки и опять была сгенерирована новая сессия.

Comment: Заказчик утверждает (он заинтересованное лицо в этом случае и доверять нету смысла.. да и повода за лет 5 работы не было), что сначала выполнял именно п2, а уже потом п3. Поясняя это тем, что с неправильным временем у него сайты с SSL начинают выбивать ошибку, т.к. дата не корректная.

Comment: Ну собственно и вариантов всего 2. Данные профиля браузера (с куками) были во временных файлах, которые покрашились со сбоем и не перенеслись в основной профиль, что произошло бы при корректном выходе. Или из-за времени перегенерились куки

Comment: Вопрос именно в том, почему заказчик был авторизован под другим пользователем, под которым авторизовался более чем месяц назад, а может и больше.. т.е. на его памяти он вообще не помнит, когда это было.. если бы перерегистрировались, то просто был бы запрос на новую авторизацию. Я прав?